# Why a computer and the local server are permanently disconnected, after an application getting no responding?

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking, windows-server-2008

I have nine computers and one server in my studio, and these machines are connected to one router (wire/wireless), and I use static IP addresses for these machines. They can ping each other. All computers need access data stored on the server.

In recent days, **three** of my computers encounters a problem (they other six computers work fine, and I cannot not find any similarity of these three computers): When I use an application (i.e., XrayVision) on these three computers to access the data in the server, the application got stuck (no responding). After this, the computer cannot connect to the server anymore (the computer cannot ping the server and vice versa, the computer and the server cannot discover each other as well). When I change the IP address of the computer, it can recover the connection with the server (ping successfully). But if I use that application again, this strange situation happens again.

It looks like that the application is the trigger that can disable the connection between my computer and the server. However, I have other six computers with the same configuration, and these computers work fine. I already ask the supporter of the software, and they told me the setting of software is find, it should be some problem of the network.

Do you have any idea why this happens? Why the computer and the server are permanently disconnected, after an application getting no responding?

Answer (score 0):

It was Trojan. I found there is a thread named **serverGUI** that exhausts 95% CPU resources in the server. Once I clean it, everything becomes fine.